# How to link against an older version of GLIBC?

Tags: c++, c, static-linking

I am compiling on a machine with `GLIBC_2.27` (Ubuntu 18.04) a shared library to be loaded on a machine with `GLIBC_2.17` (Centos 7). While essentially every other library can be linked statically into my shared library, glibc cannot. So, I scanned the library with `readelf` for references to GLIBC_2.27 and rewrote every function linked to it. That was successful for every function except for `glob@GLIBC_2.27`. I do not call `glob()` explicitly. How do I find which function or library called `glob()`?

Comment: I have no idea if this works, but what if you ran the program in `gdb`, put a breakpoint on `glob()` and get the backtrace (`bt`) from there?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you just compile your shared library on the OS (CentOS 7) you need to use it instead of Ubuntu - this will save you a lot of pain and time.

Comment: Get yourself a Docker and then (even possibly **older**) Centos image and build your image there. This is actually how many many Python C extensions for Linux are built [(manylinux)](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The docker solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @KevinZ then you should write an answer about it :D (and modify the question slightly - not how to tell which library called, but how to compile :D)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I changed the question name. If you repost your comment as an answer, I will accept it, because I have nothing significant to add to your answer. It was a linking issue to begin with.

Comment: @KevinZ but I don't know how *you* did it :D